# Java JDBC stored procedure into List<T>

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to write a method that utilizes an interface made by someone in my company. The interface method is set to return a type:

```
<T> List<T>
```

and takes amongst others a parameter of type:

```
RowMapper<T> rowMapper
```

I want to use a stored procedure with some parameters and so far i have the following:

```
SimpleJdbcCall getYearWeekOptions = new SimpleJdbcCall(getDataSource())                          .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess().withProcedureName(procedureName)
.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(PARAMETER_COMPANY_ID, Types.VARCHAR))
.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(PARAMETER_MIN_YEAR, Types.NUMERIC))
.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(PARAMETER_MIN_WEEK, Types.NUMERIC));

getYearWeekOptions.returningResultSet("yearWeekOptions", rowMapper);
Map<String, Object> result = getYearWeekOptions.execute(companyId, yearStart, weekStart);
```

So my question is, how do i return this "result" in the correct format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the values exist in the result map you can do something like :

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```

If you want to return the keys :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(m.keySet());
```